# How can we search HashMap<String, String> object inside with out loop HashSet<HashMap<String, String>>?

Tags: java, android, filter, hashmap, hashset

```
    HashSet<HashMap<String, String>> Assets = new HashSet<>();
    HashMap<String, String> Items=new HashMap<>();
    Items.put("AssetId","1");
    Items.put("AssetName","Table");
    Items.put("AssetType","1");
    Assets.add(Items);
    Items=new HashMap<>();
    Items.put("AssetId","2");
    Items.put("AssetName","Chair");
    Items.put("AssetType","1");
    Assets.add(Items);
    Items=new HashMap<>();
    Items.put("AssetId","3");
    Items.put("AssetName","Computer");
    Items.put("AssetType","2");
    Assets.add(Items);
    Items=new HashMap<>();
    Items.put("AssetId","4");
    Items.put("AssetName","Printer");
    Items.put("AssetType","2");
    Assets.add(Items);

    HashSet<HashMap<String, String>> AssetsFiltered= Assets.filter("AssetId","1,3");
```

I need something like this:

- If we are calling that function with `key` and Specified `value` we should get a filtered `HashSet<HashMap<String, String>>` object. Any Scope?.

Or any other easy way to do this type filtration. I am ready to change this `HashSet` concept.

Please note I don't want code contain any type of loop such as for, while, do while etc.

Comment: Please provide an example output given some `key` and `value`.

Comment: I guess the output would be a HashSet containing 2 HashMap which have AssetId = 1 or 3 as well as other prperties like AssetName and AssetType @VladislavVarslavans

Comment: By saying "don't want code contain any type of loop such as for, while, do while etc", do you mean that you want a solution with complexity less than O(n) ?

Comment: something like this , Set<HashMap<String, String>> AssetsFiltered = Assets.stream()
      .filter(asset -> 
              List.of("1","3").contains(asset.get("AssetId")))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());.  But in my case it is not working.It is supporting in My API version it need 24 or above .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try in kotlin code,
first we need to change the HashSet as Sequence and filter by key with the value you want.

the code like this :

```
    val Assets: HashSet<HashMap<String?, String?>> = HashSet()
    var Items: HashMap<String?, String?> = HashMap()
    Items["AssetId"] = "1"
    Items["AssetName"] = "Table"
    Items["AssetType"] = "1"
    Assets.add(Items)
    Items = HashMap()
    Items["AssetId"] = "2"
    Items["AssetName"] = "Chair"
    Items["AssetType"] = "1"
    Assets.add(Items)
    Items = HashMap()
    Items["AssetId"] = "3"
    Items["AssetName"] = "Computer"
    Items["AssetType"] = "2"
    Assets.add(Items)
    Items = HashMap()
    Items["AssetId"] = "4"
    Items["AssetName"] = "Printer"
    Items["AssetType"] = "2"
    Assets.add(Items)


    val filter = Assets.asSequence().filter { pred -> pred["AssetId"] == "2" }
    val AssetsFiltered: HashSet<HashMap<String?, String?>> = filter.toHashSet()

    val filter2 = Assets.asSequence().filter { pred -> pred["AssetId"] == "1" || pred["AssetId"] == "2" }
    val AssetsFiltered2: HashSet<HashMap<String?, String?>> = filter2.toHashSet()

    val filter3 = Assets.asSequence().filter { pred -> pred["AssetId"]!!.toInt() >= "1".toInt() && pred["AssetId"]!!.toInt() <= "3".toInt() }
    val AssetsFiltered3: HashSet<HashMap<String?, String?>> = filter3.toHashSet()

    Log.e("Assets Test", "Test $AssetsFiltered")
    Log.e("Assets Test", "Test2 $AssetsFiltered2")
    Log.e("Assets Test", "Test2 $AssetsFiltered3")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But in this case  { pred -> pred["AssetId"] == "1" || pred["AssetId"] == "2" }  filter case is fixed to two numbers right? can we make this dynamic? i mean n number cases will be there.

Comment: @AnuragKrishnan of course you can. Exactly how I did in my reply. In Kotlin you can also write an extension function to the Set class which filtering the way you want getting key and allowed values as parameter. You could then call that function directly from your Assets variable without having to pass the whole set to the method like I did in Java.

Comment: @AnuragKrishnan check the edited answer, I added condition for dynamic condition, you can add condition as you want as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Stream.filter? Something like the following should do the trick:

```
Set<HashMap<String, String>> AssetsFiltered = Assets.stream()
      .filter(asset -> 
              List.of("1","3").contains(asset.get("AssetId")))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This is also going to be NPE safe in case you don't have any Asset with the ids you are trying to filter for.

If you want it to be more generic and be able to pass dinamically key and value you could have something like this:

```
public Set<Map<String, String>> filter(Set<Map<String, String>> assets, String key, List<String> values){
    return assets.stream()
      .filter(asset -> values.contains(asset.get(key)))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

If you need the allowed values to be passed as a single string like in the example you gave you can always call a `.split(",")` on it.

Comment: hai, there is a problem with stream in my project it is not supporting api level less than 24.Mine is 22

Comment: @AnuragKrishnan Then I cannot see how you can filter without classic iteration methods.

Comment: if nothing is working i will change that.Before that i want to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether its a good idea,But i Resolved with the following code.its working for me.

```
 fun filteredAssetList(key: String, value: String, IsIn: Boolean): HashSet<HashMap<String?, String?>> {

        try {

            val filter2 = Assets.asSequence().filter { pred -> getFilterCase(pred, key, value, IsIn) }
            val AssetsFiltered2: HashSet<HashMap<String?, String?>> = filter2.toHashSet()
            return AssetsFiltered2;

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val Assets2: HashSet<HashMap<String?, String?>> = HashSet();
            return Assets2;
        }
    }

    fun getFilterCase(Item: HashMap<String?, String?>, key: String, value: String, IsIn: Boolean): Boolean {
        val lstValues: List<String> = value.split(",").map { it -> it.trim() }
        var IsFound: Boolean = false
        if (IsIn) {
            lstValues.forEach { str -> IsFound = (IsFound || Item[key].equals(str)) }
        } else {
            IsFound = true
            lstValues.forEach { str ->
                if (Item[key].equals(str)) {
                    IsFound = false
                    return@forEach
                }
            }
        }
        return IsFound
    }
```

Parameter `IsIn` using for the case **contain** or not **contain**
if `IsIn` is `true` it will return all the asset list which is in the filter value
and
if `IsIn` is `false` it will return all the asset list which is not in the filter value.

But i am using `forEach` here.LOL..